# Using \xspace inside \bm (package bm) causes error "incomplete \iffalse"

Tags: bm, xspace

I would like to use the spacing \xspace command inside the command for bold maths: \bm of the bm package.
But I obtain an "Incomplete \iffalse" error, as in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\bm{x^2 \xspace}$
\end{document}
```

The reason why I need \xspace inside math mode, is that I use to define commands that work fine both when called inside and outside math mode. The reason is that when writing text sentences, I am lazy to switch to and from math mode every time I talk about a concept, here is an example (disencouraged by Mr Carlisle's answer):

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\adva}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Adv}^A}\xspace}
\begin{document}
Denote \adva the advantage of adversary A in the game.

We have: $\adva<\epsilon$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question to address your comments. Thanks again Mr Carlisle!

Comment: I would definitely code this as `\newcommand{\adva}{\mathrm{Adv}^A}` and `Denote $\adva$ the advantage ...`  simpler definition, faster code, and clearer source allowing clear syntax highlighting of math commands. and spaces taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid `\xspace` in general (despite the fact I wrote it) and would certainly ensure it never appears in math mode. It is bad style generally to use `\ensuremath` in document level commands, TeX is designed to have a clear distinction between math and text, the fact that `\sin` makes `sin` in math and an error in text is a feature not a problem.

If you really must you could do

```
\newcommand{\xtwo}{%
  \ensuremath{x^2}%
  \ifmmode\else\expandafter\xspace\fi
}
```

but I wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks Mr Carlisle, it works!
In case you would find them helpful, I would thus have two questions on what is good practice.
(1) Without \xspace, then how to preserve spaces after commands ? Is there a better way than  

`\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\word}{word}
\begin{document}

this \word\ should have a space after it.

\end{document}'

(2) Is there a "good practice" way to have a single command \xtwo able to display the same object, e.g., x^2, both in text and math mode ? (I understand from your answer that this goes against the philosophy of TeX, so I expect no answer)

Comment: @Matthieu as egreg indicated if you used `$x^2$` there would be no problem with space after the expression or `\newcommand \x[1]{x^{#1}}` and `\x{2}` similarly. The number of cases you need a fixed constant command like `\xtwo` at all is small and the number of times you need one to work in text and math is so small the problem really doesn't occur often enough to worry about and you can use `\xtwo\ `